# ajax load variable into div, pass var to php

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

When I click an url, i want a div to show the id of the url.
I cant get the div to show the value of the id.
What am I doing wrong here.

I have the following div :

```
<div id="details">
</div>
```

I also have the following anchor (between php tags) :

```
<a id=\"rapportshow\" idnr=\"".$row[0]."\" href=\"vakgroep.php?id=".$row[0]."\" > ". $row[1]."</a>
```

and then I have the following javascript :

```
 $('.container').on('click', '#rapportshow', function(event){
                  event.preventDefault();
                  var idnr = $(this).attr('id');
                  url = "vakgroep.php?idnr="+idnr;
                  console.log(url);
                        $("#details").load(url, function() {
                        });
                  });
```

And last I have vakgroep.php :

```
<?php 
echo "hi! "; 
$idnr2 = $_GET['idnr']; 
echo "aaa " . $idnr; 
?>
```

the console logs the url and shows : vakgroep.php?idnr=rapportshow
When I click the url I expect the div to show

> hi! aaa rapportshow

But it shows

> hi! aaa

Comment: You have `$("#details").load("vakgroep.php"?indr="+url`, I think it should be `.load(url)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how I could realize what I really wanted :

```
$('.container').on('click', '#rapportshow', function(event){
                  event.preventDefault();
                  var idnr = $(this).attr('idnr');
//                url = "vakgroep.php?idnr="+idnr;
//                console.log(url);
//                      $("#details").load(url, function() {
//                      });
                        $.ajax({
                    type:"get",
                    url: "vakgroep.php",
                    data: {variable1 : idnr},
                    success: function(data){
                    //do stuff after the AJAX calls successfully completes
                    $('#details').html(data);
                        }
                    });

                  });
```

and in vakgroep.php

```
<?php
echo "hi! ";
//$idnr2 = $_GET['idnr'];
 $ajax_var1 = $_GET['variable1'];
//echo "aaa " . $idnr;
echo "bbb " . $ajax_var1;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have already built the entire url, but again you were appending it as the value for idnr. Try this

```
$('.container').on('click', '#rapportshow', function(event){
                  event.preventDefault();
                  var idnr = $(this).attr('id');
                  url = "vakgroep.php?idnr="+idnr;
                  console.log(url);
                        $("#details").load(url);
                  });
```

And your php has to be. String concatenation is done using (.) in php. Also your variable that is appended is wrong. It has to be $idnr2 instead of $idnr

```
<?php
echo "hi!";
$idnr2 = $_GET['idnr'];
echo "aaa ".$idnr2;
?>
```

For String operations refer [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: tx, that was also a mistake. but after I fix this, still the same result

Answer (score 1):

Problem #1: `echo "aaa " + $idnr;` the + symbol isn't for concatenation in PHP like it is in JS. You want `echo "aaa " . $idnr;`

Problem #2: The PHP $_GET magic array is calculated once by the server, at page load. When you update the URL via JS after the page has loaded, that will not change the values of the $_GET array in PHP. You would have to do a page reload with the new URL to see that $_GET var in PHP natively.

There is no real "fix" for this other than taking some time to think about what you really want to do with that parameter, and decide whether you should do a page reload, or use JS rather than PHP to get what you need done.

Comment: Oke, I changed this, and the result has slightly changed. 
Is there no way to pass a variable without reloading the entire page?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo "hi!";
$idnr2 = $_GET['idnr'];
echo "aaa ".$idnr2;
?>
```